# Update Record After for loop

Tags: apex, trigger, update, loop

I'm updating OpportunityLineItems when a date changes on the record. Somehow this code works in that I capture when the field is edited, add to a map and then updates the field to the expected value. The problem is it's not committing the change to the database. I can see in the debug log the Start_Date_Renewal__c gets update to the date but the record doesn't show it.

I think I need to put an update at the end but when i try update oli; it says variable does not exist. I know that I don't want the update inside the loop so what do I need to do to update the record?

Method:

```
  private void hasDateRangeChanged(Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> dateRangeChanged = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> renewals = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (OpportunityLineItem item : newMap.values())
    {
        if ((item.Start_Date__c != oldMap.get(item.id).Start_Date__c) || (item.End_Date__c != oldMap.get(item.id).End_Date__c))
        dateRangeChanged.add(item);
    }
    System.debug('dateRangeChanged is:: ' + dateRangeChanged);

    renewals = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, Start_Date_Renewal__c, End_Date__c, End_Date_Renewal__c, Opportunity.ContractTerm__c 
                FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                WHERE Id in:dateRangeChanged];

    System.debug('Renewal list is:: ' + renewals);

    for (OpportunityLineItem item : renewals) 
        parentIds.add(item.OpportunityId);
        Map<Id, Opportunity> parents = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, ContractTerm__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :parentIds]);

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli: renewals)
    {
    oli.Start_Date_Renewal__c = oli.Start_Date__c.addMonths(Integer.valueOf(12)); //need to add in ContractTerm__c from parent record map
    oli.End_Date_Renewal__c = oli.End_Date__c.addMonths(Integer.valueOf(12));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this part of a trigger? Make sure you apply your logic in the `before` event if so.

Comment: it's in a trigger handler on after update.

Comment: Just move it to `before update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this section of the [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) article in the `Apex Developer Guide`:

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

Make sure you update the values in the `before update` event.

---

You also need to update the trigger reference records.

Instead of:

```
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : renewals)
```

use:

```
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : newMap.values())
{
    Integer term = (Integer)parents.get(oli.OpportunityId).ContractTerm__c;
    // addMonths
}
```

Comment: I can still see in the debug the new value, but the field doesn't show the value.

16:22:16.0 (217386455)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[149]|com.salesforce.api.interop.apex.bcl.DateMethods.addMonths(Integer)
16:22:16.0 (217434951)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[149]|this.End_Date_Renewal__c|"2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"|0x59eeb8c2

In the record the date shows 2018-08-01 which it was at the start of the transaction.